# Can anyone identify the artist of this piece?

Tags: identify-this-song, guitar

I heard this guitar piece and would love to learn it, but am unable to identify it's name or artist.  The on-line source couldn't remember who it was or where he got it.  Any help would be appreciated.

[mp3 of piece on google drive:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4QtTYjYwVTsTVdmRDJXeTl2ZG8/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's "[Sunday Shine (Reprise)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aVqvn5SOIaQ)" by Ben Woolman. For future reference, I managed to find this using the [Shazam app](https://www.shazam.com/apps), a great resource when you can't remember the name or artist of the song but have the song available to play.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**Ben Woolman** -----
[Sunday Shine](http://www.benwoolman.net/wisdomdelusion/s/sunday_shine)